# Constructing tests for a Angular feature

Tags: angularjs, tdd

I'm trying to write a test for a  Angular features I've created. But I'm having some trouble getting into the workflow.

Users can click on a element (a div) and then Angular saves some data into my database,

The controller looks like this,

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {
  movieAdd.add()
    .then(function(response){

      $scope.movieListID = response;

      createMovie.create({
        title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
        release_date:   $scope.movieListID.release_date,
        image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
        movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
      }).then(init);

    })
}
```

And the service looks like this,

```
function httpPromise (url) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
    method:'JSONP',
    url: url
  })
    .success(function(data){
      deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(){
      deferred.reject();
    });
  return deferred.promise;
}

service.add = function(searchquery){
  var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text();

  return httpPromise(
    baseUrl + movieID + '?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=' + '&append_to_response=releases&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  )
}
```

The idea is that when a user clicks on a link with the text "add movie" the `$scope.addMovie` function triggers. This function does a call to the `add` function inside the `movieAdd` service.

The movieAdd service add function does a JSONP data request from a URL (created by inserting the ID of a movie into the URL). When that is done the `movieAdd.add` function stores the data inside the `movieListID` scope and then it creates a movie.

So I understand how it works, but what are some factors I can/should write tests for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have following cases to test -

1. Add-Movie failure
2. Add-Movie successful and Create-Movie failure
3. Add-Movie successful and Create-Movie success

First thing I'd suggest is to pass 'movieID' as a parameter, rather than finding it from the DOM.  Let the 'controller' do that.

Here's a test for the last case of success-success ->

```
it('should successfully add a movie and create it on success', function() {
  var movie = {
    'original_title':  'Mask of Zorro',
    'release_date': '1/1/2001',
    'image': '/some/image/path',
    'movie_id': 'some_id'
  };
  var addMovieDeferred = q.defer(), addMoviePromise = addMovieDeferred.promise,
      createMovieDeferred = q.defer(), createMoviePromise = createMovieDeferred.promise;
  spyOn(movieAdd, 'add').and.returnValue(addMovieDeferred);
  spyOn(createMovie, 'create').and.returnValue(createMoviePromise);

  $scope.addMovie();

  addMovieDeferred.resolve(movie);

  scope.$apply();

  expect(movieAdd.add).toHaveBeenCalled();

  createMovieDeferred.resolve();

  scope.$apply();

  expect(createMovie.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
    title:          'Mask of Zorro',
    release_date:   '1/1/2001',
    image:          '/some/image/path',
    movie_id:       'some_id'
  });

});
```

You could do the 'error' cases similarly by doing a 'deferred.reject'.

And depending on your 'init' function which is finally called, you could assert on method calls or scope values.

For the '$http' part, you could write a separate '$httpBackend' test that'll assert on the formatting on the URL primarily depending on the input 'movieID' parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It makes some sense! Going to try some stuff out tonight. Thanks you.

Comment: Always happy to help.